# Running unit tests on Mac with MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Finally, I've got my Mac and tried to re-compile and run my project with Xamarin.iOs
Since, PCL is not yet supported, I had to create a copies of .sln and .csproj and replace references to MvvmCross-Binaries and it works (thanks, Stuart). I hope Xamarin will give more elegant solution soon.

However, I couldn't compile and run unit tests on Mac - Mono 4.5 is not installed, and I didn't find Cirrious.MvvmCross.Test.Core.dll.
So, is it possible to run this kind of unit tests on Mac or we just test it in Windows platform?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to build and run the 4.5 assemblies using the latest mono 3 releases. Further, the latest mono alpha release should also contain 'proper' support for portable class libraries.

Alternatively, if you'd rather work off of stable xam releases, then you'll probably need to create your own version of a .net4 core test assembly - there are only 2 small classes so this shouldn't be too hard to do - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Cirrious/Test/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Test.Core

As well as on mac testing, I know some people also use the on device test runners - especially for iOS where the aot compilation makes on-device testing important.

Comment: I succeed to create Test.Core for .net4 project, and some tests are compiled and run good. However, I failed to compile any test with using ViewModels until I replaced ICommand to IMvxCommand. Still, some tests failed to compile with internal compilation error (probably template generic issues), and other tests stuck on running WebRequest response...
I still new in iOs and its experience, and don't understand why application compiled and runs good on simulator, while tests have problem.Of course, this is not Mvvm issue, but if you have some mac unit tests, I would very appreciate
Thanks Stuart